# What does "!" (exclamation mark) means in http header "Cache-Control: !no-store, !bypass-cache"?

Tags: http-headers, cache-control

I noticed that the page http://www.r7.com has the following http reponse header:

```
Cache-Control:!no-store,!bypass-cache,max-age=22s
```

What does the "!" exclamation mark character mean? 
Is that a negated expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification for `Cache-Control` ([RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2)) doesn't include any exclamation marks.

This is unspecified behaviour. Only the operators of that website know what they mean, but general clients are unlikely to support it.